# Overriding Serializer's update() Function Fails

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a view that calls patch()

```
class ValidateResetPasswordView(views.APIView):
    def patch(self, request, token):
        serializer = ValidateResetPasswordRequestSerializer(instance=request.user, data=request.data, partial=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        .
        .
        .
        etc
```

My serializer overrides update() to encrypt the password as

```
class ValidateResetPasswordRequestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, required=True, allow_blank=False, allow_null=False,
                                     write_only=True)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.set_password(validated_data.get("password"))
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

My serializer doesn't catch empty requests. For example, if a client sends out an empty json, my patch() gets processed successfully given no key was provided.

```
{

}
```

I expect to get an error that says `password is required`, or the like. To prevent this issue, I had to manually validate whether a key exists or not within update() function as follows.

```
class ValidateResetPasswordRequestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, required=True, allow_blank=False, allow_null=False,
                                     write_only=True)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        if len(validated_data) == 0: # force validation
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'Password is required')
        validated_data.get("password")
        instance.set_password(validated_data.get("password"))
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Am I violating any coding standards in here. Is there a better, correct, way to validate against empty requests?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right with writing the Validator Serializer. There is no need for `update()`, you just need to validate incoming data in your view. So, your validator is going to look like this (though I suggest using `min_length` for password validation):

```
class ValidateResetPasswordRequestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, required=True, allow_blank=False, allow_null=False,
                                     write_only=True)
```

The way to integrate it with your view:

```
class ResetPasswordView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ValidateResetPasswordRequestSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            # update password here and return status code 200
```

You set your serializer to be `ValidateResetPasswordRequestSerializer`, you pass request data to it by saying `self.serializer_class(data=request.data)` and then you check if recieved data is valid with `serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)`. If data is not valid Django will raise an exceptions since flag is set to `True` with relevant message to user (something like 'Password is required', 'Blank is not allowed' etc).

Comment: Voted up for min_length. Your answer doesn't answer my question. I wanted to keep patch() for ValidateResetPasswordView and patch() triggers update() within the serializer

Comment: Hm, I understand. Well, if you first validate data with raising the exception, which you do, your view should return `HTTP 400 Bad Request` if password was not provided in JSON. You couldn't fetch it from `validated_data` otherwise. Update should be called with `serializer.save()` which should execute if data is valid, meaning that passwors is in the JSON. Can't se how empty JSON goes through.